# How to remove .html from admin

Tags: permalinks

I am using plugin you can see plugin `http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/`
After activating this plugin it add .html at the end of page permalink.
WE can see this .html extension

`Dashboard->Pages->Edit`

below the title its show permalink its editable its by default take .html as an extension for each page.
But my problem is that for particular page I dont want .html extension.Is it possible.
please help me its very urgent.I shall be very thankful to u

Comment: Why do you need that `.html` extension in the first place? It is unnecessary. But since you are using that plugin, I would suggest writing an exception in `functions.php` for that file.

Comment: Can you specify for which page you don't want to have the `.html` extension and why you need the .html extension for most pages?

Comment: @hakre client previously site totally html mean not having any any admin.He wants to convert that site in wordpress.and also want the same url in wordpress.Wordpress bydefault functionality is it when we change permalink structure it take tite as permalink.He wants same url bcoz seo is alredy done for this site.

Comment: You can mimic most of the old URLs using the .html in permalinks and then you could add redirects for the exceptions. This should work with SEO as well.

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes the plugin is pretty useless because of two reasons:

1. You can setup the permalinks on your own by adding .html to it. There is no need for the plugin.
2. As Shahas Katta commented, there is genereally no need to have .html at the end of URLs.

As I don't know your site nor your needs very well, it can be totally valid that you want to have .html at the end of most URLs on your blog. So point 2. is a bit subjective.